# Changing the values of matrix is changing the weights of the model

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network, numpy-ndarray

I am working with neural network weights and I am seeing a weird thing. I have written this code:

```
x = list(mnist_classifier.named_parameters())
weight = x[0][1].detach().cpu().numpy().squeeze()
print(weight)
```

So I get the following values:

```
[[[-0.2435195   0.05255396 -0.32765684]
  [ 0.06372751  0.03564635 -0.31417745]
  [ 0.14694464 -0.03277654 -0.10328879]]

 [[-0.13716389  0.0128522   0.24107361]
  [ 0.45231998  0.15497956  0.11112727]
  [ 0.18206735 -0.22820294 -0.29146808]]

 [[ 1.1747813   0.9206593   0.49848938]
  [ 1.1558323   1.0859997   0.7743778 ]
  [ 1.0287125   0.52122927  0.4096022 ]]

 [[-0.2980809  -0.04358199 -0.26461622]
  [-0.1165191  -0.2267315   0.37054354]
  [ 0.4429275   0.44967037  0.06866694]]

 [[ 0.39549246  0.10898255  0.32859102]
  [-0.07753246  0.1628792   0.03021396]
  [ 0.323148    0.5103844   0.16282919]]

....
```

Now, when I change the value of the first matrix `weight[0]` to `0.1`, it changes the values of the original weights:

```
x = list(mnist_classifier.named_parameters())
weight = x[0][1].detach().cpu().numpy().squeeze()
weight[0] = weight[0] * 0 + 0.1
print(list(mnist_classifier.named_parameters()))
```

```
[('conv1.weight', Parameter containing:
tensor([[[[ 0.1000,  0.1000,  0.1000],
          [ 0.1000,  0.1000,  0.1000],
          [ 0.1000,  0.1000,  0.1000]]],


        [[[-0.1372,  0.0129,  0.2411],
          [ 0.4523,  0.1550,  0.1111],
          [ 0.1821, -0.2282, -0.2915]]],


        [[[ 1.1748,  0.9207,  0.4985],
          [ 1.1558,  1.0860,  0.7744],
          [ 1.0287,  0.5212,  0.4096]]],
...
```

What is going on here? How is `weight[0]` connected to the neural network?

Comment: I think they are the and the difference is just due to rounding? Try subtracting the first tensor from the second and see what the difference is?

Comment: You mean `weight[0] - weight[1]`?

Comment: Please be more precise. Are you surprised that the model weights changed? Were you expecting copy happening? Or are you refering to a diff between 0.2411 and 0.24107361?

Comment: I meant subtracting the 2nd matrix of the 2nd weight tensor from the 2nd matrix of the first weight tensor. The difference will most likely be zero which indicates that the only difference is due to different printing defaults.

Comment: @lejlot, yes. I am surprised why changes in `weight[0]` affect the values of network weights.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Apparently, when copying `np arrays`, you are supposed to use `copy()` otherwise it's a pass-by reference. So using `copy()` helped.